# How to click one of the href links from output that doesn't have a particular word in it?

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, html-parsing

I've parsed a list of href links and it's titles from a webpage. I want to click all the links that don't have the word "[$]". Here is my code.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import webbrowser
from selenium import webdriver
import urllib.request
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

browser = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\vasanth\Downloads\Compressed\chromedriver.exe")
browser.get("http://englishworldwide.ning.com/events/event/listUpcoming")
tip = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(tip, 'html.parser')
link = soup.find_all('div', {'class': "wrap xg_lightborder"})
for dept in link:
    lilly = dept.find_all('ul', {'class': 'clist'})
    for h3 in lilly:
        sill = h3.find_all('li')
        for sec in sill:
            tap = sec.find_all('div', {'class': 'tb'})
            for lip in tap:
                tappy = lip.find_all('h3')
                for lips in tappy:
                    tom = lips.find_all('a')
                    for pos, lee in enumerate(tom):
                        sappy = lee.get('href')
                        result = re.sub(r'<.*?>', "", str(lee))
                        print(result)
                        print(sappy)
```

---

Here is my output. And I want to click all those links which don't have the word "[$]" on its title.

```
C:\Users\vasanth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\python.exe      C:/Users/vasanth/PycharmProjects/Youtube/jill.py
LEWWWP's round the clock Google+ Hangout Club!
http://englishworldwide.ning.com/events/lewwwp-s-24-7-google-hangout-club
Weekly Wednesday LEWWWP Site Text Chat
http://englishworldwide.ning.com/events/weekly-wednesday-lewwwp-site-text-chat-952
Improve your speaking fluency [$] faster-paced
http://englishworldwide.ning.com/events/improve-your-speaking-fluency-faster-paced-45
Exam Prep speaking practice [$] Answer, Discuss, Repeat
http://englishworldwide.ning.com/events/exam-prep-speaking-practice-answer-discuss-repeat-29
Transcription / Pronunciation class [SLOWER-paced / Novice level]
http://englishworldwide.ning.com/events/transcription-pronunciation-class-395
```

Process finished with exit code 0

**EDIT 1:**
I have found another step ahead to find those links which don't have "[$]" in it. But I can't open those links by its positions. But the following method doesn't open those specific links.

Here is the rest of my code...

```
tricky = BeautifulSoup(str(tom), 'html.parser')
href_links = lambda tag: (getattr(tag, 'name', None) == 'a' and not '$' in tag.get_text())
for pos, final in enumerate(tricky.find_all(href_links)):
    simmpy = final.get('href')
    print(simmpy)
    if pos == 2:
       webbrowser.open(simmpy)
    else:
       break
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check if link contains dollar sign:

```
s = "This be a string"
if s.find("$") == -1:
print "$ not found"
else:
print "Found $ in string"
```

Comment: I am using Python. :)

Comment: The equivalent syntax in Python would be `if "$" not in myString:`